# Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet with JDK16.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to use create dynamic web with Eclipse for Enterprise and Web Developers, but when I add JRE System Library[jdk - 16.0.1] an error will occur:

```
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. tomcat-project      Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)
```

I did change **Project Facets** to *java version 16* but nothing work! I not found where I can customize *version* to *16.0.1* .Other than using JDK *16.0.0*, is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: @Robert  Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Comment: As far as I remember Eclipse 2021-03 has no built-in java 16 support, only via [add-on](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-16-support-eclipse-2021-03-419) Java 16 support is possible. But I would recommend to upgrade to 2021-06 which has built-in Java 16 support.

Comment: Yep, thanks you, I will try with 2021-06